# Abrir un archivo desde el vba de word

Tags: excel, vba, macros, ms-word

***Buenas tardes***, soy nuevo en vba en word, veo que se puede aplicar parecido al vba de excel (macro), pero no puedo abrir un archivo desde vba word como lo hacia en excel.

Esto si funciona en macro excel, pero no en vba de word.

**Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()**

Workbooks.Open ("prueba.xlsx")

**End Sub**

Slds.
Luis A.

Comment: La colección `Workbooks` pertenece exclusivamente a VBA de Excel. Dependiendo del tipo de archivo que quieras abrir, tendrás que crear una instancia a Excel o a otro programa para abrirlo desde Word.

Answer (score 0):

No hay tanta información de VBA de Word como de Excel, pero al ser un mismo lenguaje, hay cosas muy parecidas. Adapta esto a tu dilema:

```js
Application.Documents.Open "D:\Varios\Manuales\VSTOv3CTPTutorial.doc"
```

Saludos.